# C-->How to coordinate processes behaviour using semaphore?

Tags: c, message-queue, message, semaphore

I'd like to ask you guys for some help in understanding `C Semaphores`.
Basically I want to create two Processes `Child` and `Parent`.
Of course their behaviour is different:

1) Child Process does some `sleep()` and sends a Message on a previously created Message Queue

2) Parent Process does some `sleep()` too but then reads the Message sent on the Queue.

I need Child Process to be first one to run, of course.
I managed to do this using `wait` and `waitpid` system calls, and now I would like to do it using `Semaphore`.
Below some code I managed to write:

A) Functions I'm using from `semaphore.h`

```
//In order to create a Semaphore

int createSemaphore(key_t semaphoreKey){
    int semaphoreId = semget(semaphoreKey, 1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if(semaphoreId == -1){
        printf(RED "Semaphore Creation failed\n"RESET);
        return -1;
    }
    return semaphoreId;
}

void semaphoreWait(int semaphoreId, int semaphoreNumber){
    struct sembuf buffer;
    buffer.sem_num = semaphoreNumber;
    buffer.sem_op = -1;
    buffer.sem_flg = 0;
    int done = semop(semaphoreId, &buffer, 1);
    if(done == -1){
        printf(RED "Wait on Semaphore %d failed\n" RESET, semaphoreNumber);
        return;
    }
}

void semaphoreSignal(int semaphoreId, int semaphoreNumber){
    struct sembuf buffer;
    buffer.sem_num = semaphoreNumber;
    buffer.sem_op = 1;
    buffer.sem_flg = 0;
    int done = semop(semaphoreId, &buffer, 1);
    if(done == -1){
        printf(RED "semaphoreSignal Failed on Semaphore %d\n" RESET, semaphoreNumber);
        return;
    }
}
```

B) Functions I'm using from `messageQueue.h`

```
typedef struct message{
    long type;
    char text[255];
}message;

//Creates a Message Queue and returns its ID
int createMessageQueue(key_t semaphoreKey){
    int queueId;
    queueId = msgget(semaphoreKey, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    return queueId;
}

//Sends a Message on Message Queue queueId
void sendMessage(int queueId, message* messaggio){
    int sent = msgsnd(queueId, messaggio, strlen(messaggio->text) + 1, 0);
    if(sent == -1){
        printf(RED "Sending the message %s failed on Message Queue %d\n"RESET, messaggio->text, queueId);
        return;
    }
}

//Receives a message from Message Queue queueId
void receiveMessage(int queueId, message* messaggio, int type){
    int received = msgrcv(queueId, messaggio, 255, type, 0);
    if(received == -1){
        printf(RED "Receiving message on Message Queue %d failed\n" RESET, queueId);
        return;
    }
}
void setText(message *mex, char text[], int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        mex->text[i] = text[i];
    }
}
```

C) At last my `main.c` file:

```
#include "semaphore.h"
#include "messageQueue.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    pid_t piddo;
    message mex, mex2;
    mex2.type = 1;
    key_t semKey = ftok("/temp", 0);
    key_t mexKey = ftok("/temp", 1);
    char text[] = "This is a message sent from Child to Parent";
    int semId = createSemaphore(semKey);
    int mexId = createMessageQueue(mexKey);
    switch(piddo = fork()){
        case -1:
            printf(RED "Fork ERROR\n" RESET);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case 0:
            printf(CYAN "Child Process %d has started\n" RESET, getpid());
            printf(CYAN "Doing some useless sleep\n" RESET);
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                printf(CYAN "Sleep %d\n" RESET, i);
                sleep(1);
            }
            printf(CYAN "Useless Sleep Finished\n" RESET);
            printf(CYAN "Now I setup Message to send\n" RESET);
            mex.type = 1;
            setText(&mex, text, strlen(text));
            printf(CYAN "Settings saved, Now I send Message\n" RESET);
            sendMessage(mexId, &mex);
            printf(CYAN "Message succesfully sent, Child Process %d has finished\n" RESET, getpid());
            //Now I want Parent Process to know Child has finished
            semaphoreSignal(semId, 0);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        default:
            printf(YELLOW "Parent Process %d started\n" RESET, getpid());
            printf(YELLOW "I have to wait for Child Process\n" RESET);
            //With this wait Parent Process should wait for Child to have finished
            semaphoreWait(semId, 0);
            //Now Parent knows Child has finished
            printf(YELLOW "Looks like Child Process has finished\n" RESET);
            printf(YELLOW "Doing some useless sleep\n" RESET);
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                printf(YELLOW "Sleep %d\n" RESET, i);
                sleep(1);
            }
            printf(YELLOW "Useless sleep finished\n" RESET);
            printf(YELLOW "Receiving Message sent by Child...\n" RESET);
            receiveMessage(mexId, &mex2, 1);
            printf(YELLOW "Message Received: \n" RESET);
            printf(YELLOW "%s\n" RESET, mex2.text);
            printf(YELLOW "All Done, Parent Process %d has finished\n" RESET, getpid());
            semaphoreSignal(semId, 0);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

As you guys may notice, `Child` and `Parent` processes are not synchronized in this `main.c` file as I would like.
My question is: 
How can I make sure Child does everything his code demands before Parent starts?
Thank you `:)`

Comment: RED, YELLOW and CYAN are variables defined in another header file. They just color text in output so are irrelevant here.

Comment: I think that POSIX semaphores are easier to use:  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html.   Anyways, It doesn't look like you are using System V semaphores correctly as it doesn't get initialized via `semctl`.  It might be easier for it to create the semaphore, initialize it to 1, and have parent wait on zero, until child decrements it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't clear - it's best to clearly state the problem that you observed. Since the program is trying to synchronise the parent and child and you ask about that, I assume you're seeing the parent trying to read the message before the child has signalled completion via the semaphore.

As Fred notes, you aren't initialising the sysV semaphore; you also don't delete it when you are done ([this may help](http://www.thejaywalker.net/2010/12/system-v-semaphores-how-not-to-design.html)). I assume that the semaphore, if it doesn't already exist, starts with value 0. Since it's a IPC tool and not owned by any single process, it persists between runs.

Your program (what we can see of it) calls `semaphoreSignal` twice and `semaphoreWait` once, so each time the program runs it increments the value of the semaphore by 1 and leaves it that way; so on subsequent runs the semaphore value starts >0 due to the leftover value from previous runs and so the parent runs immediately.

Also you should check the return value of ftok(3); `/temp` isn't a path that normally exists.